# Does one say "allegory for" or "allegory of"?

Tags: word-usage

How does one correctly use the word "allegory" in a sentence? For example:

> This story is an allegory **[for|of]** pride.

I have seen examples of both:

> the long poem is an allegory **of** love and jealousy

[[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/allegory)]

> To that extent, are his experiences an allegory **for** life?

[[Your Dictionary](http://sentence.yourdictionary.com/allegory)]

Comment: Normally it would be an "allegory *of* " something. However, it is possible for some contexts to require the preposition *for:* "The Lord of the Rings is an allegory for the World Wars" (Wikipedia, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allegory )

Comment: There are two ways to refer to an allegory. One is the title of it, which refers to the literal elements in the story, as "the allegory of the Cave" , as cited in the Wikipedia article you mentioned. The other way to refer to it is in regard to the things it symbolizes. In that sense, one uses "for" , e.g. It is an allegory for human self-centeredness. The syntax works the  same for  "parable".

Comment: I'd like to say the difference hinges on how 'tight' the allegory is. Thus 'an allegory of the life of Francis of Assisi' but 'an allegory for life'. But, after searching on Google, I've found that 'allegory of' is by far the more common choice no matter how specific or general the events being allegorised. I'll continue to buck the trend.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock, this makes the most sense. Why don't you add it as an answer?

Comment: can't cut/paste it and too lazy to type it again. Thanks for the compliment, though.

Comment: Is it not similar to diagnosis of and diagnosed with.

Answer (score 3):

> There are two ways to refer to an allegory. One is the title of it,  which refers to the literal elements in the story, as "the allegory of  the Cave" , as cited in the Wikipedia article you mentioned. The other  way to refer to it is in regard to the things it symbolizes. In that  sense, one uses "for" , e.g. It is an allegory for human  self-centeredness. The syntax works the same for "parable".

Answer given by [Brian Hitchcock](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/95331/brian-hitchcock) (in the comments, but with a technical problem making it an answer).

Comment: Please add substance; we expect your take in an answer besides citations. For instance, what technical problem are you referring to? How have you improved on the comment to make it worthy of an answer?

Answer (score 2):

Allegory *of* seems to be overwhelmingly favored over allegory *for,* per this [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=allegory%20of%2C%20allegory%20for&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3). The Ngram utility does not allow my attempted comparison of *“Pilgrim’s Progress* is an allegory for/of,” but with the “Pilgrim’s” removed it showed no hits at all for the *for* option and some for the *of* option. Trials of “read/interpreted as an allegory of/for” also showed strong preference for *of.*